# Ignore Daylight Time to get Time Zone Abbreviation

Tags: php, timezone

The code below it is getting all US timezones abreviations.

```
$date_time_zones = [];
$date_time_zones_identifiers = \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(\DateTimeZone::PER_COUNTRY, 'US');
foreach ($date_time_zones_identifiers as $date_time_zones_identifier) {
    $date_time_zone = (new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('UTC')))
        ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($date_time_zones_identifier))
        ->format('T');
    $date_time_zones[$date_time_zone] = $date_time_zone;
}
var_dump($date_time_zones);
```

Nowadays, it is returning:

```
array (size=8)
  'HDT' => string 'HDT' (length=3)
  'AKDT' => string 'AKDT' (length=4)
  'MDT' => string 'MDT' (length=3)
  'CDT' => string 'CDT' (length=3)
  'EDT' => string 'EDT' (length=3)
  'PDT' => string 'PDT' (length=3)
  'MST' => string 'MST' (length=3)
  'HST' => string 'HST' (length=3)
```

I would like to get these abbreviations without considerate `Daylight Saving Time`, so, `PST` instead of `PDT` for example. Is it possible?

Comment: Instead of using  now use the first of the year when DST is not in effect

Comment: @JohnConde good call! Ty!